# Tic, Tac, stub your Toe

Tags: code-golf, binary-matrix, tic-tac-toe

Find the max number of Xs you can fit onto a rectangular tic-tac-toe board of length *l* and height *h* without ever having 3 consecutive Xs in a row **diagonally**, horizontally, or vertically.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge so shortest code wins!

### Input

A single line containing values *l* and *h*, representing the length and height of the tic-tac-toe board, separated by a space.

### Constraints

```
1 ≤ l ≤ 2,147,483,647
1 ≤ h ≤ 2,147,483,647
```

### Output

A single number representing the number of Xs that can fit on the tic-tac-toe
board without three in a row

### Sample Inputs and Outputs

```
Input -> Output
2 2 -> 4
3 3 -> 6
2 3 -> 4
4 4 -> 9
```

### Explanation

4 Xs can fit on a 2x2 tic-tac-toe board without having 3 Xs in a row anywhere

6 Xs can fit on a 3x3 tic-tac-toe board without having 3 Xs in a row anywhere

4 Xs can fit on a 2x3 tic-tac-toe board without having 3 Xs in a row anywhere

9 Xs can fit on a 4x4 tic-tac-toe board without having 3 Xs in a row anywhere

### Credits

Lukas Zenick for creating the problem

### Extra Data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJvlxdGm8TocR3sh3leRIpqdzmN3bB_z8N-VrEKSCwI/edit

[image: TIC TAC 2x2] [image: TIC TAC 3x3]

Comment: Can we get non-square test samples?

Comment: @Fatalize Just give me a minute to get a good one and I'll add it.

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah my bad. Diagonal, horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Welcome to code golf, and this looks like a nice challenge!  A tiny improvement would be to format the test cases so that they can easily be input together into code to be tested, without a lot of separate copy-pasting: see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101/95126)

Comment: @Dominic Updated!

Comment: By 3 X's in a row does that include 3 X's in a row but seperated by Spaces?

Comment: Like `X X O X` where O is a space?

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer "consecutive", so no that an allowed arrangement without three in a row :)

Comment: My bad, i don't mostly pay attention to adjectives :/

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has a very simple formula: l * h if l and h are less than 3; otherwise ceiling(l * h * 2/3). I would love to be wrong though

Comment: @chunes the max we got for 4x4 was 9 while your formula produces 11. It might work for some solutions but it's probably just pseudo for now. It might work if diagonals weren't in place.

Comment: The sequence of the table's diagonals is on the OEIS - [A181019](https://oeis.org/A181019).

Comment: Still mostly brute force, but I at least got it fast enough to solve 4×4 on TIO: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLLasMwELznK4RPK1AhhtxyMkkLLiSEtreQgxsrtYgetiXFrX/elWQ3UWkp1IfFMzsa7Wr3WBXtURV8GHJZW7O14pW20ODlLMaVw5nW7E3CnKDeoZ3VFViC9t3BoZNqEeTy2FJBpaElvDBBNTQEVRhjdBVftXEebYp6pYQoZOlFO241hJDME4LOeKKS1KHM5LKk7163prfrOPbfctZVjFMEmfyASNk7i8yZ3ze24BrOBG2YZMIK2Lv/R8UkPNELbTWF55oz4xWuLoI6/Gv6C/nSrrobefDUVplQxq2bECJ/4vuGiqAHxo17Y0dOBW5UabmCelQJ39ooDhbNSP84FZLfj@bSrNmFlXQk/m3GpIuuwtj1L9uVstKAIChJ0zQJMwnTnVYnWpBpiVrm9KtCG4in2ftZDsMCLYa7C/8E)

Comment: What's the winning criteria? The tags suggest [tag:fastest-code], but how will it be measured?

Comment: Since you've tagged it as a `[fastest-code]` challenge, you'll have to add how you're going to test the speed of each answer. E.g. are you going to test them on your own PC (in which case, what are the processor specs?) - and maybe installation instructions in answers might be useful then. Or, and this is probably easier, are you going by [TIO](https://tio.run/#) or [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run) execution time? EDIT: @pajonk beat me to it while I was typing..

Comment: This is an integer linear programming problem.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/245570/9288). This is also finding the maximum density still life in some 2D cellular automaton.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I do not plan on installing new languages to my own pc so I will currently just be running it on TIO

Comment: @pajonk See above

Comment: TIO is [discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12707/39242) for fastest-code challenges. Also, the fastest program that prints the answer for *l* = 9, *h* = 9 is going to be absurdly fast, and might just degenerate toward `print(42)` via “optimizations” that will be meaningless to measure and won’t correlate with speed for larger inputs. Take a look at other [tag:fastest-code] challenges for inspiration—it’s better to structure them to ask for the most number of values of some sequence in a fixed amount of time, rather than for a single fixed value in the shortest time.

Comment: Hey @JohnBGoode why'd you accept my edit?

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer My edit's weren't reopening it so I decided to try yours and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnBGoode edits dont reopen, people have to reopen them. edit place it on the reopen queue

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Ohhhhhh my bad

Comment: It landed me in hot water in TNB that's why I asked.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 270 bytes

```r
function(x,y,z=expand.grid(rep(list(1:0),x*y)),l=lapply(1:2^(x*y),function(i)matrix(unlist(z[i,]),x)))max(sapply(l[sapply(l,function(m,f=function(m)apply(cbind(m,2,matrix(rbind(2,m),nrow(m))),1,function(x)max((y=rle(x))$l[!!y$v])))max(f(m),f(t(m[nrow(m):1,])))<3)],sum))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDbboMwEETf8xWOkgdvta3KpY2CypcgKhEwqSVjkDGtnZ@ny6UllfrmOeOZXa0ZrSxtUdpWpGM96NLKVnOHHm@pcF2hq6erkRU3ouNK9pYHyTOge/AAqFJVdJ3yxMJ3PjH8bZDQFNZIxwc9x26ZxJyCAGQ43i9Blf08tmSDdboJWPzyInVFVohrrZkBSUBt2i/6SAsFW4ubx3CfGiVIwFFl@70/fubrAjUlsOaWN9maTwKczLcIcuwH6tsuQ3NCYAcW7zYU/YeiCb3eoXhBpz8ontB5d7hnLxMLQsbNoNnFs0Yw1ZaFUj5hVjaif2wHyz6EETB@Aw)

Unfortunately I didn't notice the 'fastest code' tag and started working on this assuming that it was 'code golf', so this isn't very fast (and I won't golf it any further).  But it at least calculates the test cases without timing-out...

Comment: Well, probably time to revisit this, as it indeed became Codegolf :D

Comment: Hmm...  maybe I'll try to cut-off 69 bytes then...

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 402 bytes

Saved 250 bytes thanks to [@py3_and_c_programmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110681/py3-and-c-programmer).

This was originally a [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge. Now it became a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), but I'm too lazy to golf it.

```
f[m_,n_]:=Total@LinearProgramming[Table[-1,m*n],SparseArray[Flatten@MapIndexed[{#2[[1]],#}->1&,Flatten[{Table[m*i+j+k+1,{i,0,n-1},{j,0,m-3},{k,0,2}],Table[m*(i+k)+j+1,{i,0,n-3},{j,0,m-1},{k,0,2}],Table[m*(i+k)+j+k+1,{i,0,n-3},{j,0,m-3},{k,0,2}],Table[m*(i+k)+j-k+1,{i,0,n-3},{j,2,m-1},{k,0,2}]},2],{2}],{(m-2)n+m(n-2)+2(m-2)(n-2),m*n}],Table[{2,-1},(m-2)n+m(n-2)+2(m-2)(n-2)],Table[{0,1},m*n],Integers]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBSwMxEIX/ykJBts0EmvSkYKkgQkGhYG9DKKlN13Q3syXNQQn57Wu26oKoPc2b8L034TkdXo3Twb7ortuj2wBt1M3tug26WTxaMtqvfFt57ZylCtd62xjkAtyEFDwftT@ZO@/1Oz40OgRDiyd9XNLOvJkdxpFEFErBKPG5uIIvBONniptYdmA1ExAtTIG4SBAPWTk@y6rOSiYF33BpWT3OhgGfDbi4gNd/GS7k818G@fNCAqkg9s5YOi7HxFxJeTJ5Xs@6r2eIjhJ6/7/wwE0hY@dilxRMZfxJdfctrrylgPlLhU0Fnxd77GWutejfBBTXSXUf)

Using the built-in [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html). Gives the results from `1x1` to `9x9` in 40 seconds on TIO.

Comment: Now that it's a `code-golf` challenge (my fault), you might want to change it to this code:

Comment: `f[m_,n_]:=Total@LinearProgramming[Table[-1,m*n],SparseArray[Flatten@MapIndexed[{#2[[1]],#}->1&,Flatten[{Table[m*i+j+k+1,{i,0,n-1},{j,0,m-3},{k,0,2}],Table[m*(i+k)+j+1,{i,0,n-3},{j,0,m-1},{k,0,2}],Table[m*(i+k)+j+k+1,{i,0,n-3},{j,0,m-3},{k,0,2}],Table[m*(i+k)+j-k+1,{i,0,n-3},{j,2,m-1},{k,0,2}]},2],{2}],{(m-2)n+m(n-2)+2(m-2)(n-2),m*n}],Table[{2,-1},(m-2)n+m(n-2)+2(m-2)(n-2)],Table[{0,1},m*n],Integers]`

Comment: which is 250 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 311 bytes

```ruby
->m,n{(0...1<<(m*n)).map{|z|
  k=("%0#{m*n}b"%z).scan(/#{"(.)"*n}/)
}.reject{|w|
    (w.map(&:join).grep(/111/)[0]||w.transpose.map(&:join).grep(/111/)[0])||
    w.each_cons(3).any?{|x|x.transpose.each_cons(3).any?{|z|
      k=z.join.to_i(2)
      [273,84].any?{|z|k&z==z}
  }
}}.map{|c|c.flatten.count ?1}.max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3ZFhT4MwEIa/8ysatpkW8RjbEo0Z8jdMkCxdw3CbFAYlbND@dix2MzNR42e/Xe/e93r3XFmvT/0m6O@eMpd3eAoA/nKJM4cTAhktOtlKC6F9gO3JdNTpvFrbk5ZAxSjH3qizMRBbZz1iKSiTXcJEJ5vBgxBuhhb45nGXbzmBtEwK7Pm@75FoGkvZgCgpr4q8Sn7REWmaNZBQ9rpiOa/wnADlp7CTR3m8avKNoDXmYYMWhvYg8tUWz8g5Hc3u5@7DIv6U72/aIGiVLitLKYOASQabNypEwoHlNRco9IfSUfVpYMhp/SHYRDqMdfgjxz@S1J//I5ZIXozNV4w49MnyMGx7IU2Nkl7v4Iy927HnzMxJLKuoRYWwD7A4k83k9YtLcwbl2C/CVtr94TC2NFq489gMn1b1Wk/ghs@kfwc)

Nothing particular, still using brute force.

Comment: I get 7 for (4,3), and your code seems to get 9 (I think).  Can you check [this](https://tio.run/##lZFvb4IwEMbf8ykI6tKyWuTP1BkYX2MJIwsSNOooCCUotJ/dtaJRl8Xou971nufufldU8/1h4R2GHykiLRhhjE3XBalOIMRplLesYYqqbjygDUa9VuT5XBs0EJdxRIDRazWAoSayBlQ4LpJ1EtOW1VIDiGszlro29GVUSzvwMltnKwLxskhyYJimacBgFDJWY1pEpMyzMrlTB2fSSQxJhjbEEdn7LdsxmUgvib1sLkeugx2yw4txsJeh9MU0@14BCx4Lgwl6GyPHmaKJjUxnjKx3C1niPXXCk2XDNi@N5zVcCLjCeUcmZjFe/ESUJgTHWUWo6pvya8cPS68DKuq33iIQz/A0@b94HwQsmt8i/gv5HuaHGB8BP4z4CcjPYVbZuUF9Sxj4JnS3EsT5CFFXGV1vpPeN176hW921FCWvaKkCE2PnBD1l1xFh3YW4rn1RjQv1UdHJloGNnNNCy7KaiwmQ/wkPvw)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen: Should be fixed now

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>262</s> <s>254</s> 212 bytes

```python
def f(x,y,D={}):
 R=[i for i in range(2**x)if'111'not in bin(i)]
 for _ in[0]*y:D={(a,b):bin(a).count('1')+max(D.get((b,c),0)for c in R if(a&b|a>>2&b>>1|a*4&b*2)&c<1)for a in R for b in R}
 return max(D.values())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRaoQwEEXf/YqBgmbsdDExCCtdn/YL9lWkJNZsA20Uq0Xp7rdb47YU9u1y5swdmG4e3lqXPnVzNy/La2PAsIlmOh6@r5gHcDqUFkzbgwXroFfu3DARxxNaE3HOI9cOfqCtYxarYFNfVlImVTznawtTpDH3c4W7uh3dwCIe4eOHmthxd24GxjTVSAn61dqXncAapkJ9UUUhQl0U/KJiGepYYFg/801UN9FHvcVrAH0zjL2DW/OXeh@bT4a4dL1djxomSCDCA8jgj6SUbiQL/p30zpEkN7L/JaVhlize/4QT8AQrb5acJGW0J56RSEhklGYkRbX8AA)

-8 bytes thanks to 12944qwerty

Rows are encoded in binary, and `R` is the list of all possible rows.

In any given iteration `i` of the second for loop (starting from 0), `D` is a dictionary where `D[a,b]` is the largest number of Xs that can fit in an `X` by `i` board where the first two rows are `a` and `b`.

The new `D` is calculated by iterating over every possible first 2 rows `a,b`, and setting `D[a,b]` to the number of Xs in row `a` plus the maximum value of `D[b,c]` where `c` is every row that could follow `a,b`.

This algorithm takes time \$y\cdot8^x\$ and space \$4^x\$, solving 1x1 to 9x9 in 20s on TIO.

Comment: BTW, Python 3.10 has a function `int.bit_count()` which is shorter (and also multiple times faster) than `bin(int).count('1')`

Comment: @97.100.97.109 PyPy currently only goes up to python 3.9 and is much faster. (on my computer `f(9,9)` using PyPy and `bin(a).count('1')` took 17 seconds while python3.11 with `a.bit_count()` took 60 seconds)

Comment: [254 chars](https://tio.run/##VZBBboMwEEX3nGI2JTMwiTCwQoRVTpBthCqb4tRSaxCFCtTk7NQEJW021v9vNM@W26l/b2yybad2mue3WoPGkSc@7k9RyYf9z5UyD3TTwSsY61gwZm5mgnhhxjE4luHSQ/FHwGgwL2melM@7U@aMKFlRpoxFSbuqGWyPG7Gh8FOOeNid6x5RcUUc0bJa3YUofXVBWRQx@aiKQtAFHVujj3EQjFuxTCnP3eFXubgJ5CpYorrFqwdd3Q@dhfXGb/kx1F9INLedcY/RGLMTePeWcPKvxU8t5fTRThoNG4LHN3TSnmsUDCKikuZf) by replacing `in range(x)` with `in[0]*x`

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + `lpSolve`, <s>202</s> <s>194</s> 149 bytes

```r
function(m,n,`[`=`for`,x=outer(1:m,1:n*1i,`+`)){i[x,j[c(1,1i,1+1i,1i-1),F<-rbind(F,x%in%(0:2*j+i))]]
lpSolve::lp("max",!!x,F,"<",min(m*n,2),,seq(x))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7BCoJAFEX3fYUKwXt6g8ZVDLr1B1pKMGUKT/Rpk8VA9O1mm7s4i3OuX7uoXLuXNotMSiMUrnal6ybvEMrptbSejB1hrKZG4DLH/JE6oK8bMtiQyf4jB8OoioO/id6pQtiL7ulo87TPhPly2Q3zeRrerbXDTMl4DQniOKBCUiQYZWunipyBZ/ugwPxdtw8kkWhk7IlnL7pQR4LNtv4A)

A golfed version of an external ILP solver-based solution, which I started working on when this was a fastest code challenge, but got closed. Works slower than Wolfram though, but still manages 8x8 on TIO.

In lieu of a proper explanation, here is an outdated, but somewhat ungolfed version:

```r
library('lpSolve')

f = function(m, n, p = m*n, r = -1:1, l = {})
{  
  if(p == 1) return(1) # Edge case for 1x1
  for(i in 1:m) for(j in 1:n) for(k in 1:4)
  {
    d = list(          # Directions
      cbind(i+r, j),   # Vertical
      cbind(i, j+r),   # Horizontal
      cbind(i+r, j+r), # Diagonal
      cbind(i-r, j+r)  # Antidiagonal
    )
    x = matrix(0, m, n)
    try(x[d[[k]]] <- 1)
    l = rbind(l, c(x))
  }
  lp(direction = "max", objective.in = rep(1, p), const.mat = l, const.dir = "<=", const.rhs = 2, all.bin = T)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 149 bytes

Expects `(width)(height)`.

```javascript
w=>h=>eval("for(o=0,m=1<<w*h;M=--m;o=M|(g=k=>v=k&&1+g(k&k-1))(m)<o?o:v)for(p=q=0;(v=M&2**w-1)&v/2&v/4|v&p&q|v&p/2&q/4|q&(q=p)/2&(p=v)/4?0:M>>=w;);o")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYtLDoJAEET3noK4mHSjyEdiokOPJ@AQRPkoYDNiho13x9ad0aSqk5fqdy1cMZ7ul@ER3PhczhXNE5mGTOmKDpYV34EpWvcUZ9nkNzqnIOg1U/6Emloyjlql4lUNrWqDGBF6zPjIB4dvdSBLkQZHuUp8f5IH5cJEmj6dGpR9X2ErbBVYGlBILIdheowOuTE0adS8xPnEt5G7ctNxDRUkKEEvDL108b1sUfJZdosfZ/vfSVHyWfbzCw)